# MYSQL multiple COUNT() with multiple conditions in single query

Tags: mysql

I'm newbie in MYSQL.

I have a table like below:

---

```
colmnA    colmnB
A           x
A           y
B           x
B           z
C           x
D           null
```

---

What I want to achieve is something like:

```
SELECT
COUNT(distinct colmnA) WHERE colmnB IS NOT NULL AS deployed,
COUNT(distinct colmnA) WHERE colmnB IS NULL AS undeployed
FROM table
```

### which will be resulted in:

```
deplyed    undeployed
3          1
```

---

is there an elegant way to achieve this with a single query?
thanks for help

As far as I've searched, the most closed solution is combining SUM() with CASE condition, ex:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN columnB IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0) AS deployed
```

but it will include duplicated count, and there is no way to add DISTINCT into SUM().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use count?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN colmnB IS NOT NULL THEN colmnA END) deployed,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN colmnB IS NULL THEN colmnA END) undeployed
FROM   table;
```

Comment: Thanks! it's working! and I apologies for my poor searching skill -_-

Answer (score 0):

`select max(deployed) as deployed, max(undeployed) as undeployed from
 ( select count(distinct columnA) as deployed, 0 as undeployed
     from testtable
     where columnb is not null
   union
   select 0 as deployed, count(distinct columnA) as undeployed
     from testtable
     where columnb is null
) as foo;`

@JRD's answer works too.